# Unable to add an Access app

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, microsoft-access

I am trying to add an Access App to my Sharepoint site on Sharepoint Server 2016 but it gives me the following error:
"Sorry, something went wrong. An unexpected error has occurred."

I have full permissions. Also I checked if all services work and there were 2 for Access - both working.

Any idea?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install, set up, and provision Access apps for SharePoint in Access Services.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/set-up-and-configure-access-services-for-access-apps?redirectedfrom=MSDN